# How to delay explosion animation

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine

How can i delay the explosion animation? it is starting the first frame. I want to start other frames, for example 50 or 80. how can i do that? i try to change active to passive from rigit body. but it is not work! [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. i did find. how i will do that. you can look that image: [image]